# The Java servlet print an HTML page with a button that calls JS function that doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, servlets

I have a simple Java servlet that prints an HTML page. The HTML page contains a button that calls a JavaScript function. The JavaScript function works on HTML file, but it doesn't when the servlet prints the HTML pages. Why?

```
    out.println("<html>"); 
    out.println("<head>");

    out.println("<title>Pagina di annotazione</title>");
    out.println("<script src=\"application.js\" defer></script>");
    out.println("<script src=\"canvas.js\" defer></script>");
    out.println("<style>");out.println("#drawboard {background: url('"+imm.get((int)request.getSession().getAttribute("imgselezione"))+"') no-repeat top center;}");
    }

    out.println(".container {text-align: center;}");
    out.println("</style>");
    out.println("</head>");
    out.println("<body>");

    out.println("<h1>Pagina di annotazione </h1>");

    out.println("<form>");
    out.println("<menu type=\"toolbar\">");
    out.println("<button type=\"button\" onclick=\"lanciaEvento('salvadato');\">");

    out.println("Memorizza");              
    out.println("</button>");
    out.println("<br>");


    out.println("<a href=Scroll?value=indietro > Indietro </a>");
    out.println("<a href=Scroll?value=avanti > Avanti </a>");out.println("</menu>");

    out.println("<canvas id=\"drawboard\" width=\"800\" height=\"600\"></canvas>");
    out.println("</form>");
    out.println("</body>");
    out.println("</html>");
    out.close();
```

The function that doesn't work is lanciaevento('salvadato').
I repeat: the function works good in a HTML page without servlet.

I suppose I've got a syntax problem with the buttons, or some problems with buttons.

Comment: I think you can narrow this down. The servlet is probably not serving what you expect to the browser. From your browser, view source of the HTML received from the servlet. (In Chrome, view -> developer -> view source). Does the HTML your browser shows match the working HTML? Probably, there is one part that is mangled up, and you can focus on fixing that.

Comment: The world will be a better place if people stop using servlets for "view" and start using JSP instead.

Comment: Are the files `application.js` and `canvas.js` present in your webapp folder?

Comment: It works fine in Chrome, but it doesn't in Eclipse Luna. I dont know why

Comment: I resolved just doing show HTML in Eclipse Browser. Maybe this is a Bug of Eclipse Luna